# watir open each link of a page

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I need to scrape some info on a website that has a table where each row contains a link.

I want watir to click each link in that table, grab some info from the generated page and go back to the previous page.

```
t = browser.table(:class => "tblElencoProdotti")

t.links(:class => "TXT10b").each do |l|
  l.click
  #do some stuff
  browser.back
end
```

Unfortunately the back action brings me to a "Document Expired This document is no longer available" error.

This works if I manually do the operation on my default ff session and hit the back arrow, but somehow it does not work if I do that in the watir opened window.

Comment: FF may be relying on its cache. You may be able to see this if you click Refresh after going back manually in FF.

Comment: If the above is the case, you'll have to implement your own "cache" by storing what you need from the page, rather than telling WATIR to re-fetch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you need to actually click and go to back with browser each time?

Why not store all the links and then visit them one by one:

```
browser.table(:class => "tblElencoProdotti").
  links(:class => "TXT10b").map(&:href).
  each { |url| browser.goto url }
```

**Update**:

If the links are only clickable due to JavaScript `magic`, then try something like this:

```
links_count = browser.table(:class => "tblElencoProdotti").links(:class => "TXT10b").size
links_count.times do |index|
  browser.table(:class => "tblElencoProdotti").links(:class => "TXT10b")[index].click
  browser.back
end
```

This solution should clear the cache. I'm not sure, but maybe there's some better way to relocate everything and not rely on already cached elements.

Comment: it's all javascript and I haven't yet figured out how it works, so clicking on it is the only way I have to get to the page I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample code to visit all the links in your specific table, and perform any action on the visited page.

```
links = Array.new
    ii = 0
    browser.table(:class => "tblElencoProdotti").links.each{|li|
      link = Struct.new(:href, :text)
      links[ii] = link.new(li.href, li.text)
      ii = ii + 1
    }         

    links.each { |li|        
                 browser.goto(li.href)                  
                 #Do your stuff                   
    }
```